# Para que servem e como usar os parâmetros do mailto?

Tags: html

Eu sei que a palavra chave `mailto:` usada no atributo `href` nos link é usado para abrir o cliente de e-mail do usuário para o envio do e-mail, mas não sabia que existiam alguns parâmetros extras, que podem ser usados junto com a palavra chave `mailto:`, estes são:

- `cc`
- `bcc`
- `subject`
- `body`
- `?`
- `&`
- `%20`

Para que servem e como usá-los?

Comment: Já posso dizer que os dois penúltimo não são "parâmetros" – são apenas partes da URL. O último, um espaço em URL encoded. Os demais parecem ser auto-explicativos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"mailto:[...]" como você disse, é só uma forma de abrir o cliente de e-mail, e você pode especificar os seguintes parâmetros:

**mailto:example@gmail.com** - especifica o destino do e-mail

**subject** - especifica o campo "assunto" do e-mail

**body** - especifica o campo principal do e-mail, é onde você escreve sua mensagem

**CC** - Envia uma cópia do e-mail para todos os endereços de e-mail especificados

**BCC** - envia uma cópia do e-mail para todos esses destinatários de e-mail mas sem avisar ao destino original da mensagem, é como se você enviasse uma mensagem no Whatsapp para X pessoa, printasse a conversa, e enviasse o print para as pessoas A, B, C, etc. As pessoas A, B, C terão uma cópia da conversa sem que a pessoa X saiba

**?** - isso é pra separar o domínio usado pelo "mailto" dos parâmetros da URL, por exemplo: https://qualquerdominio.com/uma-rota?parametro=valorDoParametro

**&** - Isso é pra especificar um segundo ou terceiro, ou quarto parâmetro, por exemplo:
https://qualquerdominio.com/umaRotaQualquer?parametro=valorDoParametro&outroParametro=valorDoOutroParametro

**%20** é usado no lugar de usar um espaço, digamos que eu queira enviar uma mensagem com o assunto "Bom dia", ao invés de deixar esse espaço em branco na URL: "https://domioqualquer.com/umaRotaQualquer?subject=bom dia", a URL está inválida, é necessário substituir o espaço em branco por %20, e então fica dessa forma:
"https://domioqualquer.com/umaRotaQualquer?subject=bom%20dia"

Espero que tenha entendido, qualquer dúvida que ficou, é só perguntar :D

Comment: Muito obrigada! deu para entender agora.